# Missing write permissions in directory pub/static when run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, permissions, static-content

The day before, I updated a new module and it was working normally. Now, when I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, I receive the below Exception. I tried setting permissions to 777 (or 770) for the `pub` folder in Magento 2 but it is not working.

> [Exception]
>     Missing write permissions to the following directories: 'pub/static'

Comment: did u manage to resolve this problem ? if so pls post the solution.

Comment: Are you have same issue ?

Comment: yes i am facing the same issue. how did u resolve it ?

Comment: I comment some line code in core. Are you want do as me?

Comment: yes i want to apply that solution of yours. pls post how u did it

Comment: i posted my relsove in post below. I can try with it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR truncate `pub/static` folder.**

---

For me, I had an older installation, which probably had some symlinks and old files which no longer exist.

The issue `checkInstallationFilePermissions` is that it checks the permissions recursively. Files and folders. I had a missing symlink, and that returned false on the check if it's writable.

How to debug:

1. `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/FilePermissions.php`
2. Goto line 143 in method `checkRecursiveDirectories`
3. Add the lines `var_dump($subDirectory);var_dump($subDirectory->isWritable());`
4. Re run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

now you'll see what is really wrong, and you can fix it. **Personally i remove everything in `pub/static`**, this will be auto generated content so you should not be worried about that.

Comment: I removed pub/static completely, after I ran setup:upgrade the only folder inside pub/static is __requirejs folder. Css are missing, no styling what so ever.... Man.. do I wish i haven't done that

Comment: how can I restore everything in pub/static ?

Comment: everything was going so well.... :) i really start to despise this framework

Comment: If you remove the contents of pub/static just make sure you don't remove pub/static/.htaccess as it is part of the code base and doesn't get recreated: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0/pub/static

Comment: Perfecto!
This was it..

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this error in development because of a broken symbolic link.

I had created a file in a module's `view/frontend/web` directory that in `developer` mode was deployed to the `pub/static` directory using a symbolic link that pointed to the module's directory where the original file is stored.

At some point in development I removed the file from my module, but the symbolic link still existed in `pub/static` pointing to a file that no longer existed. I expect this would also be the case if I had renamed one of the files.

If a site is in `production` mode and has had `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` run, that actually copies the files to the `pub/static` directory instead of creating symbolic links.

In order to find this broken symbolic link I ran a command from the shell

```
find -L . -type l
```

Removing the broken symbolic link resolved the problem (for example using `find -L . -type l -exec rm {} \;`).

Comment: This was the answer to my issue as well, thanks mttjohnson!

Answer (score 6):

Inside your Magento root directory run the commands below and your issue should be gone:

```
$ rm -rf pub/static/*
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This will delete `.htaccess` file too. You need `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri no it won't. `rm -rf pub/static/*` doesn't delete dotfiles. Go ahead and try with a test directory. `rm -rf pub/static/.* (notice the dot)` would delete htaccess.

Comment: @medina Thank you 

Answer (score 2):

You should setup the permissions as it is described in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html

Comment: can you the actual permissions just cause in-case the url changes.

Comment: I try again but it not working

Comment: Do not forget to do it recursively into subdirectories: pub, pub/static, etc.

Comment: ownership is as important as permissions; check the above link and also http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html. You must have two users; a local user and the web server user

Comment: the whole idea of setting the permissions at application level is wrong so I think people should avoid the documentation at that section. it will be updated in next versions according to their github issues

Comment: I have found that, actually, Magento have no idea how file permissions should be set. Executing the various setup commands can damage file permissions even when the magento user is in the web server group. A much easier solution is to follow the single-user permissions setup, where the single user is www-data or apache (for ubuntu or centos respectively), then simply run the commands as follows: sudo -u www-data php bin/magento setup:upgrade

This way, the command is executed by the web server user and not the magento user, which maintains all proper file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This is my resolved temporary. I comment line 744 and 466 in `<magento_dir>/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php`.

This is line code:

```
$this->checkInstallationFilePermissions();
```

I need solution don't change core file.

Comment: The problem is likely due to a broken symlink (answered below) under the pub/static directory. Removing the broken symlink should resolve the problem without modifying core files.

Comment: http://newtips.co/magento/questions/91184/missing-write-permissions-in-directory-pub-static-when-run-bin-magento-setupupg.html

This will work

Comment: @EnvisionEcommerce the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is having this issue on Windows os. Just execute the command on a Administrator command prompt and it will work like a charm. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Fix bin/magento permission denied

chmod u+x bin/magento

Answer (score 0):

These folders needs to have the right permissions like described in: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html

When you remove the contents of the pub/static folder and you give the pub/static folder the permission 770, the message will not show up again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where i could not install Magento via the command line.
Simply creating the folder `pub/static` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case running upgrade command through non-root user or a user with limited permissions was causing the error. Make sure you run the upgrade command with a user with enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I verified many times write permissions and everything was good.

1. I commented this row, which throw me an exception.
2. Then I ran setup:upgrade.
3. Reverted back the row with exception
4. Issue didn't reproduce no more

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command, for the following three IP addresses:

```
<Magento-Directory>php bin\magento maintenance:allow-ips 127.0.0.1, 
<Magento-Directory>php bin\magento maintenance:allow-ips "the ip of my localhost given by the NAT-Router" and
<Magento-Directory>php bin\magento maintenance:allow-ips  "the ip of the NAT-Router"
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use this :

```
rm -r pub/static
```

it will remove all files even .htaccess

you can use this will be better :

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml
```

after that use :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have deleted pub/static (except .htacess) under the impression that it will be created upon next execution but after executing upgrade command you ended with this :)

Don't worry, execute the deploy command using -f to have everything in flow and expected.

I had the same issue but managed my old working source by following the above trick.

Answer (score -1):

just remove pub/static folder from your magento2

```
rm -r pub/static
```

then deploy static content of magento2

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

by using this process my same problem solved.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the entire pub/static directory as it contains a .htaccess file that is important, and the .htaccess file will not get recreated on any static content deploy. You could run `rm -r pub/static/*` and that should avoid removing the .htaccess file.