# data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

Tags: magento2, plugin, upgrade-script

I am trying to create a magento plugin I have create every thing required.

when I enabled the plugin then it shows the below error. What I am missing here.

> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
>   The following modules are outdated:
>
> ```
> Test_Featureproduct data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
> \#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> \#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> \#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
> \#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> \#4 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> \#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> \#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
> \#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> \#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
> \#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
> \#10 {main}
> ```

**Module.xml**
[image]
**InstallData.php**

[image]

Comment: Does the `Test_Featureproduct`  module have a etc/module.xml file with setup_version?

Comment: yes, i have create module.xml with setup_version

Comment: Did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` ? Just enabling the module is not enough, it is not yet installed. once you run this command, you it will be registered with magento

Comment: Yes I run below commands
 bin/magento setup:upgrade ;      

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: after running setup:upgrade, is the module listed in the file app/etc/config.php? Maybe it is a permissions error or some weird failure in upgrading the database

Comment: Is module listed in `setup_module` table in DB?

Comment: Thanks Maddy, That was permission issue. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/missing-write-permissions-in-directory-pub-static-when-run-bin-magento-setupupg

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me several times. What I do is go to the database, to the table
`setup_module`:

`select * from setup_module;`

and delete the extension that has the problem. In this case I would go and delete all the: `Test_Featureproduct` **line**. 
Once done, run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```