# Magento2 with Nginx and PHP7: cannot access the admin

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7

We have installed a fresh Magento 2.0.2 with PHP 7.0.4 and Nginx.
The frontend works correctly, and we can create customer accounts. 
But, the problem is we cannot access the admin. it gives an error: "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

[image]

And Debug logs show this line:

> [2016-03-15 18:47:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http:://example.com/index.php/admin/admin/index/index/key/a12f6c236de96a369096230294c30b32cfc3fe784788bfc44a3ec44009b0ed06/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   []

Nginx logs:

> 2016/03/15 19:11:12 [error] 6819#0: *5791 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 217.125.83.47, server: example.com, request: "POST
>   /index.php/admin/admin/index/index/key/9d1adcd6bb29c1491a34613a8b639c78618d0837ebcf36fbfdbabf2b7943b5a5/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9002", host:
>   "example.com", referrer:
>   "http:://example.com/index.php/admin/admin/index/index/key/9d1adcd6bb29c1491a34613a8b639c78618d0837ebcf36fbfdbabf2b7943b5a5/"

PD: http::// == http://

Our configuration files is:

NGINX:

```
server {

listen *:80;
root /var/www/example.com/web; #Use you mangeto2 location
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name example.com;

location /setup {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @setuphandler;}

# Rewrite Setup’s Internal Requests
   location @setuphandler {
       rewrite /setup /setup/index.php; }

# Rewrite Internal Requests
location / {  

        index index.php index.html;

#we have tested the 3 ways:
       try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
#      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
#      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

    location @handler {

       rewrite / /index.php;
    }

     location /pub/static {

         try_files $uri $uri/ @static;

    }

     location @static {

          rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$1? last;

    }

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/www;}

#pass the PHP scripts to f stcgi socket
location ~ \.php$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
#Magento 2 Developer Mode
#      fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "developer";  
  } 
}
```

PHP7:

```
[web2]


listen = 127.0.0.1:9002
listen.owner = web2
listen.group = client1
listen.mode = 0660

user = web2
group = client1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 0

chdir = /

php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web2/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web2/tmp:/var/www/example/web:/srv/www/example.com/web:/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /var/www/clients/client1/web2/tmp
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = /var/www/clients/client1/web2/tmp
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fwebmaster@example.com"
```

We have tried several configurations Nginx, and reinstall the Magento,

Please can someone help us.
Thank you,

Comment: Did you run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` and than `composer update --no-dev` ? If so, run composer without --no-dev.

Comment: Thank you @obscure , after composer update --no-dev Its give me this error:
Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.0.2].

But, we have the ext-zip installed (I can see'it in phpinfo()). Any suggestions.

Comment: I was saying that you should not use `composer update --no-dev -vvv` when you're in developer mode. Run `composer update -vvv` instead, without the option --no-dev. Than clear var/cache/* and var/generation/. Possibly var/page_cache/* var/view_processed/* var/di/* too.

Comment: @obscure thanks for your clarification. So we have tried in developer mode also in production mode. 
But we have the same result in the both case: 


Problem 1 - magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.0.2].
. Another suggestion.?

Comment: Could it be this: https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/zip and http://php.net/ZipArchive

Comment: @obscure finnaly we have solved the problem of ext-zip,  and after run composer update (dev mode) also tested composer update --no-dev (in production mode), but we still cannot enter to the admin

Comment: See if you have same problem in the link. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/missing-write-permissions-in-directory-pub-static-when-run-bin-magento-setupupg

Comment: I had same problem with admin and was not related to the web server. Whatever you do DO NOT DELETE pub/static contents. The symlink method provided in the answer may help. You could backup pub/static first. If this doesn't work, any debug in Magento code would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe the problem was in the version of PHP 7.0.4. The Magento install wizard was showing we had php 7.1, but was not correct. May be that was the problems about admin login error.
So we get a downgrade to 7.0.0 following this 
manual step by step:
https://gist.github.com/tvlooy/881d0d67d0ad699c38a3

Then, we downloaded Magento 2.0.2 with sample data from official site.
We have assigned the correct user to the folder `(chown -R user:group *)`.

In case of Magento with sample data is important to increase memory_limit, for that go to  /bin/magento and set

`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` (or more memory if possible)

It is important to use the appropriate Nginx configuration file. The example of this post work for us.