# Magento2 Missing write permissions to the following directories: 'site/public_html/pub/static'

Tags: magento2, upgrade, permissions, file-permissions

unfortunately i get this error when I try to do a magento2 setup upgrade

```
arredeom@chronos [~]# php public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/home/arredeom/public_html/var/generation/Composer
/home/arredeom/public_html/var/generation/Magento
/home/arredeom/public_html/var/generation/Symfony
The directory '/home/arredeom/public_html/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Ibnab_ChangeAttributeSet':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running recurring..
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Ibnab_ChangeAttributeSet':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Smartwave_Core':
Module 'Smartwave_Filterproducts':
Module 'Smartwave_Megamenu':
Module 'Smartwave_Porto':
object(SplFileInfo)#2612 (2) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(126) "/home/arredeom/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/it_IT/Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(25) "authentication-popup.html"
}
bool(false)



  [Exception]
  Missing write permissions to the following directories: '/home/arredeom/public_html/pub/stati
  c'



setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

I tried

1. `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/FilePermissions.php`
2. Goto line 143 in method `checkRecursiveDirectories`
3. Add the lines `var_dump($subDirectory);var_dump($subDirectory->isWritable());`
4. Re run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

but I don't see any changes, what can I do?
thanks

Comment: make sure there should be 777 permission on  var folder in side your Magento root dir

Comment: I set them via ftp and using command below but (except for the fact that via ftp it says that is impossible to change it for some files) it's not working

Comment: could this be this file's fault? object(SplFileInfo)#2506 (2) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(126) "/home/arredeom/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/it_IT/Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(25) "authentication-popup.html"
}
bool(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lauren I would suggest taking a look at this if you haven't already: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html .

If you do decide to use this:

1. rm -rf public_html/pub/static/* public_html/pub/media/* public_html/var/generation/* public_html/var/di
2. Correctly set permissions on public_html (chmod 755 -R public_html or 777 or whatever you want, please read link below on file permissions to understand this concept better, and then check the docs for your Linux distribution for how to make these changes)
3. *If you chose to use the umask, make sure it reflects the permissions you want...if you use 000 , then your permissions will be 777. I think this explanation of Unix file permissions is accessible: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184005
4. php public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error message says it is a permission issue.

I suggest you try to run the following commands:

```
find pub/static -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find pub/static -type d -exec chmod g+w {} \;
```

You can find more details about Magento 2 permissions in the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html).

Comment: I executed arredeom@chronos [~]# find public_html/pub/static -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; and 
arredeom@chronos [~]# find public_html/pub/static -type d -exec chmod g+w {} \; but nothing happened :\

Comment: @LaurenFrida did you try to rerun the upgrade command after running those commands ?

Comment: yes, and I get the same error

Comment: is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @LaurenFrida not recommended but could you try `chmod -R 777 ./pub/static `

Comment: does that set 777 on every folder inside static? could it be that i'm not trying with the correct user?

Comment: @LaurenFrida check my answer for a link that explains Unix Permissions. The quick answer is that the third number represents "others" or other users than the owner of the file/folder (same in *nix, really)..so if you set 777 that means the owning "user" has read/write/execute, the "group" has read/write/execute, and "others" have read/write/execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not *always* helpful here, as more often than not, this is really caused by a broken symbolic link in the pub/static directory. An example is if a file in pub/static is pointing to a certain module's file, and then that module's file is moved or deleted.

To see if there are any broken links, run the following command from the pub/static folder:

```
find -L . -type l
```

See the following for more context: [Missing write permissions in directory pub/static when run bin/magento setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/missing-write-permissions-in-directory-pub-static-when-run-bin-magento-setupupg)

Answer (score 0):

In my case running upgrade command through non-root user or a user with limited permissions was causing the error. Make sure you run the upgrade command with a user with enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the Symbolic Link  By Command

find -L . -type l -exec rm {} \;