# Error while setup upgrade magento 2.0.7?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7, setup-upgrade

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/*

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I have set 777 permission to pub but still getting

> [Exception] :
>
> Missing write permissions to the following directories: '/var/www/magento2/pub/static'

Suggest some solution.

Comment: Which command use for set 777 permissions ?

Comment: @Payal Patel - chmod -R 777 pub the permission is set but then also it gives the error

Comment: Use this command @Zest :- sudo chmod 777 -R pub

Comment: yes I used this command and  it is setting permission but still getting error

Comment: Unless you really need 2.0.7 (testing an upgrade maybe?) you should just install 2.1.1/latest at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link.

I hope this link helpful for your issue.

> [Missing write permissions in directory pub/static when run bin/magento setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/missing-write-permissions-in-directory-pub-static-when-run-bin-magento-setupupg)

You can check also below link.

> [Magento2 Missing write permissions to the following directories: 'site/public_html/pub/static'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117850/magento2-missing-write-permissions-to-the-following-directories-site-public-ht)

Comment: Thanks I followed the steps but still getting error

Comment: Check my update answer and try to follow link @zest.

Answer (score 0):

I think, First you need  create Static Content,

```
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then Run,

```
  chmod -R 777 /var/www.html/
  bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This way worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

```
 Type sudo chmod 777 -R var pub command in terminal
 then php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

hope it will works